# Relative positioning a th in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

This question came to my mind not because i am doing a project or something. It just popped up in my head.

I have read *(from some posts on stack overflow)* that `position:relative` does not affect table elements and that `top,left,bottom,right` wont work.

I tried this and found that it does affect the `th` element as shown in below snippet in some way. `top` and `left` properties actually worked on `th`.

But one thing isnt so clear about this effect, why is it that the border of the `th` stayed at its place and only the `th` migrated??? Any ideas as to why this happens?

I would really like to know if the border could be moved along with the `th`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  border: 4px solid green;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo_Geek/gna2vgoy/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting position on `tr, th, td` elements is not a cross-browser idea. so instead of that, put your content inside a container inside your `th` element and position relatively that container.

```
<th><div>THIS</div></th>
```

And the style would be:

```
th > div { border: 4px solid green;position: relative;top: 30px;left: 30px; }
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gna2vgoy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add display: block; to your th and it gets the position. You cannot position the th alone since it just moves the content.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid green;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>THIS</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But using this on an actual table with contents may  break the layout!! Thanks for the reply tho :)

Comment: Yes that's right. I suggest not using table if possible. you can achieve whatever you want without table and positioning. specially if you use bootstrap grid system